# ¿Cómo almaceno la salida a consola en una variable en coffescript?

Tags: coffeescript

En Javascript una forma de hacerlo es:

```
"use strict";
var log = console.log, logRecord = [];
console.log = input => {
  log(input);
  logRecord.push(input);
}
```

Pero quisiera hacer lo mismo en Coffeescript para guardar las impresiones a consolas en una variable y poderla comparar.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN:

```
class Solution
 constructor: ->
 main: (@args) ->
     console.log "Hello world!\n"  

log = console.log
logRecord = []
console.log = (input) ->
  log input
  logRecord.push input

greet = new Solution
greet.main("hola")

console.log logRecord
Test.expect(logRecord.indexOf("Hello World!\n") != -1)
```

### ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

Para que salga algo en mi logRecord debo correrlo así

```
class Solution
 constructor: ->
 main: (@args) ->
     console.log "Hello world!\n"  

log = console.log
logRecord = []
console.log = (input) ->
  log input
  logRecord.push input

greet = new Solution
console.log greet.main("hola")

console.log logRecord
Test.expect(logRecord.indexOf("Hello World!\n") != -1)
```

### Salida

> Hello world!
>
> [ 'Hello world!' ]
>
> Value is not what was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo harías de la misma manera, Coffeescript es solamente una sintaxis diferente, en el fondo es JavaScript

```
log = console.log
logRecord = []
console.log = (input) ->
  log input
  logRecord.push input
```

---

Esto está mal:

```
console.log logRecord
```

le tienes que pasar el mensaje que quieras guardar, es decir un string

```
console.log greet.main("hola")
```

Comment: Agrega el código completo a tu pregunta para ver que está pasando.

Comment: Listo favor de revisar la pregunta de nuevo :$

Comment: Le estabas pasando el array donde guardas los mensajes a la función, tienes que pasarle el mensaje que quieres guardar.

Comment: sí... creo que me equivoqué... la idea es imprimiren el método del objeto y leer lo impreso en consola para hacer la prueba unitaria, pero de cualquier forma falla

Comment: La prueba unitaria falla porque los strings son distintos, uno tiene la "w" en minúscula y el del test lo tiene en mayúscula

Comment: Estás totalmente en lo correcto gracias por tu tiempo. Podrás hallar el código en: http://www.codewars.com/kata/classic-hello-world/forks/coffeescript